# Web Service deployment Azure ML

Tags: azure, machine-learning, azure-machine-learning-service

I am trying to deploy a Keras model but getting an error. My code is

```
service = Webservice.deploy_from_model(workspace = ws, 
                       name = "test-classifier",
                       deployment_config = aciconfig,
                       models = [model],
                       image_config = image_config)
service.wait_for_deployment(show_output = True)
```

Error:

```
{
  "code": "GatewayTimeout",
  "statusCode": 504,
  "message": "ACI Service request failed. Reason: The gateway did not receive a response from 'Microsoft.ContainerInstance' within the specified time period.."
}
```

Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 1):

The default timeout is 1 minute.You can increase the timeout or try to speed up the service by modifying the score.py to remove unnecessary calls. If these actions do not correct the problem, use the information in this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-troubleshoot-deployment?tabs=azcli#http-status-code-504) to debug the score.py file. The code may be in a non-responsive state or an infinite loop.